# Add Kafka offset id to dataflow flex template "Kafka to BigQuery"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow

I use Dataflow flex template "Apache Kafka to BigQuery" and it works, but now I'd like to add Kafka offset id to data loaded to BigQuery, is it possible, maybe using UDF?